# Cannot install Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I am getting following error while installing Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit.

```
The following file did not match its source copy on the CD/DVD: /target/lib/firmware/phanfw.bin
```

Thank you

Comment: Now i got this error, The installer encountered an error copying files to the hard disk
[Errno 5] Input/Output error

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a problem with your .iso image, if you're installing a fresh copy. Try to download the .iso image again at Ubuntu's site, rewrite it on a DVD or USB drive, and install again.

Comment: Download via torrent client to automatically hash check, peer to peer is also faster. Torrents R the future.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I already downloaded the ubuntu again. Also downloaded torrent file too. Still i am getting error.

Comment: How are configured your partitions? EDIT: try to boot with ubuntu cd or pendrive and make a memory test. Maybe its a memory problem

Comment: I had two hard disk drives. One of them is entirely given for ubuntu.

Comment: Is the hd already parted?

Comment: Yes, and there is only one partition on that hd.

Comment: You could erase the partition and Split it to create a swap one and a ext4 to install Ubuntu. Makes your OS faster and can solve your problem :D

Comment: Have you already tried the memory test?

Comment: Not yet, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the ISO file from Ubuntu site, do `md5sum <your_downloaded_iso_file>` and compare the value with the one which is mentioned in the official website. If it doesn't match download again and try to install. This will work.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I compared the checksum with Checksums calculator. And i got the result, they are same.

Comment: The problem is that the mentioned firmware setting file has been either corrupted/isn't supporting your architecture. The reasons can be many. If you are trying to dual boot with existing windows or if the boot hasn't done properly on your bootable disk you may face this problem.